How to optimize PyTorch and Ultralytics Yolo code to utilize GPU?
I am working on a project which involves object detection and tracking. For object detection I am using yolov8 and for tracking, I am using SORT tracker. After running the below code, my GPU usage is always under 10% and CPU usage is always more than 40%. I have installed cuda, cudnn and have installed torch using cuda. I have also compiled opencv with cuda support. I am using RTX 4060 ti but looks like it's not being used.
Is there a way to further optimize the below code so that all of the work is handled by GPU and not CPU?
from src.sort import *
import cv2
import time
import torch
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(f"Using device: {device}")
sort_tracker = Sort(max_age=20, min_hits=2, iou_threshold=0.05)
model = YOLO('yolov8s.pt').to(device)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    if not ret:
        print("**No frame received**")
        continue

    results = model(frame)
    dets_to_sort = np.empty((0, 6))
    for result in results:
        for obj in result.boxes:
            bbox = obj.xyxy[0].cpu().numpy().astype(int)
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox

            conf = obj.conf.item()
            class_id = int(obj.cls.item())
            dets_to_sort = np.vstack((dets_to_sort, np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, class_id])))
    
    tracked_dets = sort_tracker.update(dets_to_sort)
    for det in tracked_dets:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = [int(i) for i in det[:4]]
        track_id = int(det[8]) if det[8] is not None else 0
        class_id = int(det[4])
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.putText(frame, f"{track_id}", (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800, int(frame.shape[0] * 800 / frame.shape[1])), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    if key == ord("p"):
        cv2.waitKey(-1)
    
cap.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


here, OpenCV is purely used for GUI and a bit of drawing. compared to the AI parts, that is negligible.

@ChristophRackwitz Do you know any libraries/package I can use instead of Opencv that utilizes GPU ?

your major computing is ultralytics or pytorch, not OpenCV.

@ChristophRackwitz I have mostly optimized the code, I am just not able to find a GPU based tracker, once I am confident, will post answer

Tracking from "sort.py" file is CPU based. Instead, you can use "model.track" from Ultralytics, which will significantly reduce CPU usage.

how do you know?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try exporting your yolo model to .engine format, it should boost your detection speed significantly. also for the tracking part you could utilize the built in Bytracker of supervision library
https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/export/
https://supervision.roboflow.com/latest/trackers/
